# Sharepoint 2010 Summary link webpart - Need to display different color for different summary link webpart

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have two summary link webpart. I applied CSS for one webpart and same CSS is applied to another webpart too .. kindly help to display different color to webparts.
.dfwp-list{background-color: #0072C6;}

Answer (score 1):

you need to write selectors specifically for the second webpart.

a not so good solution, but will do the job, is finding the id of the webpart and then write

```
#webpartid .myClass{}
```

ideally you shoukd include this in the page itself maybe in a CEWP to make sure other pages/webparts are not affected